# Elegant numerical->letter academic grade mapping

Tags: .net, oop, design-patterns, mapping, range

This is a simple example I would like to start with to expose the problem.

Consider you have a bunch of numbers, ranging from 0 to 10, and you want to map them to letter grades (A, B, C, D, F).

One can write a sequence of `if` statements testing a given number in the corresponding letter range and return the correct letter.

The question is: what pattern can be used to make this more robust and perhaps more decoupled? For instance, if instead of 5 number ranges I had 10, I would have to edit this monolithic method to add the other 5 cases. I also have no guarantee that my ranges are exclusive, even though they should be in this case.

I can imagine a `Dictionary<Range<int>, string>>` of sorts being used here, but it still does not seem enough to provide all the guarantees I'm looking for. Perhaps one could use polymorphism to model this concept in a more streamlined and extensible way?

I'm sorry for the simple example, but I'm sure this can be applied as a generic range mapping strategy of sorts to other, more complex algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

If it is something as simple as mapping positions to some other format where the positions are linearly increasing and the result is increasing by the same amount, then a simple formula can be used.

For your grade letter example, mapping 'A' to 0, 'B' to 1 etc is simply:

```
int value = ...
Character result = value -'A';
```

Most languages will map 'A' to its ASCII value so subtracting the value you want from 'A' will produce the number of letters "past" A.

If you need something more complicated like a Mapping of the ranges, then `Replace Conditional Dispatcher with Command` pattern (example shown [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1398607&seqNum=6) ) might be a good idea.

If you have something even more complicated, then something like `Chain of Responsibility` Pattern.

Here's a quick example:

You need to make an interface that has a method to determine if the Range you are providing will work for that implementation.

```
IGradeMapper{
   bool accept(Range<int>);

   String computeGrade(Range<int>);
}
```

Then your have a list of `IGradeMapper`s that are checked in order:

```
for(IGradeMapper mapper : list){
    if(mapper.accept(range)){
        return mapper.computeGrade(range);
    }
}
```

The nice thing about this way is the matchers are each loosley coupled and you can implement and add new ones to the list later (even at runtime) if you wanted.

If you you either of those patterns, then try to make the first conditions tested be the most common to make it run faster.

Comment: Very nice, exactly the kind of answer I was hoping to see. Unfortunately, this is not a computed relation, as I was specifically referring to academic grades in the question as you see. Could you perhaps devise a simple example using the chain of responsibility pattern here?

Comment: I just noticed your edit on the OP, sorry about that. Also, I think your `IGradeMapper` should take an `int` instead of a `Range<int>`. The intention here is to map a single number to a grade, given that for instance A's range is 9->10. I wonder what would be better in this case: I can create multiple mappers passing the interval and respective letter in the constructor, or create a few concrete types with the intervals and ranges hardcoded inside them.